# Array to Custom Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
dataSeries.data=[10,20,40,40,20];
```

However I would like to get each array element in JavaScript object

```
myjs=[{data:10},{data:20},{data:40},{data:40},{data:20}];
```

I have tried the following but does not work:

```
for (i = 0; i < self.dataSeries.length; i++) {
    self.dataSeriess[i].data = self.dataSeriess[i].data.map(function (x) {
        return { data: x };
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop through `dataSeries.data` and append objects to `myjs` [(jsFiddle demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/vk9x1prr/):

```
dataSeries.data = [10,20,40,40,20];
var myjs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < dataSeries.data.length; i++) {
    myjs.push({ data: dataSeries.data[i] });
}
```

Or, if you want to use `Array.prototype.map`, then you don't even need a loop [(jsFiddle demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/L1q3dv8t/):

```
dataSeries.data = [10,20,40,40,20];
var myjs = dataSeries.data.map(function(x) {
    return { data: x };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've over complicated your loops.

Here's a simple [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) example.

http://jsbin.com/waxohezozu/1/edit?js,console

```
var data = [10,20,40,40,20];

data = data.map(function (e) {
  return {
    data: e
  };
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myjs = dataSeries.data.map(function(x){
  return {data: x};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
function toObject(arr) {
   var result = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
      result.push({data :arr[i] });
   return result;
}
```